# Display values from list of structs in Elixir / EEx

Tags: loops, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a list of structs in elixir and I want to loop over them to display the values from each of them:

```
[%InvoiceApplication.Billing.LineItem{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "billing_line_items">,
  currency_type: 1, currency_value: 1.0e3, description: "sdadsaasfasf", id: 1,
  inserted_at: ~N[2017-03-14 13:56:12.982080],
  invoice: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :invoice is not loaded>,
  invoice_id: 1, item: "item1", tax: 10,
  updated_at: ~N[2017-03-14 13:56:12.982095]},
 %InvoiceApplication.Billing.LineItem{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "billing_line_items">,
  currency_type: 2, currency_value: 2.0e3, description: "dfadf asdfadsf", id: 2,
  inserted_at: ~N[2017-03-14 13:56:13.110123],
  invoice: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :invoice is not loaded>,
  invoice_id: 1, item: "item 2", tax: 20,
  updated_at: ~N[2017-03-14 13:56:13.110136]},
 %InvoiceApplication.Billing.LineItem{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "billing_line_items">,
  currency_type: 3, currency_value: 3.0e3, description: "adsfaf asfadf", id: 3,
  inserted_at: ~N[2017-03-14 13:56:13.111817],
  invoice: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :invoice is not loaded>,
  invoice_id: 1, item: "item 3", tax: 30,
  updated_at: ~N[2017-03-14 13:56:13.111829]}]
```

I need to display

```
<td> Item 1 </td>
<td> Item 2 </td>
<td> Item 3 </td>
```

Comment: This is quite trivial with `for`. Did you try writing any code for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enum.map` or `for` to do it:

```elixir
<%= for item <- @items do %>
  <td><%= item.item %></td>
<% end %>
```

or

```elixir
<%= Enum.map(@items, fn(item) -> %>
  <td><%= item.item %></td>
<% end) %>
```